# Grails: various problems around method proxying

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

My company is trying to implement an auditing service that will intercept method calls on a service if that method is annotated with a particular annotation.  For example:

```
class FooService {

  @Audit
  void pleaseAuditMe() {
    // some important code
  }
}
```

Our first shot at implementing this was to use Spring AOP to wrap the annotated methods with around AOP proxying that would record the audit data that we needed before and after the execution of the method.  While we were able to get the auditing working the solution was no good as AOP proxying will wrap any exception thrown with an UndeclaredThrowableException if the exception type is checked and not declared on the method being proxied.  Given the nature of Groovy and Grails (i.e. checked exceptions are generally not declared) it really doesn't make sense to go through and declare exact exception types on all of our methods.

Alternatively, we've tried to implement the functionality via metaclass mixins.  After getting this working we realized that any method call in a CompileStatic context doesn't go through the metaclass and, as such, does not call our proxying logic.

This seems like it must be a 'solved problem' in the Grails world but we haven't been able to figure it out.  We want:

A solution that allows us to proxy method calls without forcing us to rewrite all of our exception handling/declaration and also that works regardless of whether or not we're in a compile static context.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an AST transformation which is triggered by your Audit annotation.  This is what recent versions of Grails do with the Transactional annotation.  This avoids the need to use runtime proxies and is fully CompileStatic friendly if done correctly.

Comment: This is an interesting idea and does seem like it would work.  It also seems like re-inventing a wheel that surely someone must have already invented.  Is there no baked in method proxying approach that actually works in Grails?

Comment: Yes there are.  However, in general we are moving away from runtime proxies wherever we can.  Transactional is one example of that.  You can do all the standard Spring proxy stuff if that is really what you want to do.  If I were implementing what you are describing, I would do it in an AST transformation.  Doing so has a number of benefits including performance, ability to call from Java, improved unit testability without needing whatever creates the proxies (the code is compiled right into the class), etc.

Comment: For all of the disadvantages listed here http://groovy.codehaus.org/Building+AST+Guide I'm more than hesitant to implement this in AST.  I don't have in house AST expertise and it seems fragile from version to version of Groovy.  This auditing code is going to be inserted in all of our most critical business code so learning a new, very complicated technique on the fly seems like too much risk.  I'm really interested in implementing this in a straight forward, run of the mill runtime proxy that doesn't have these risks.  It seems really odd to me that there isn't an out of the box solution.

Comment: There is an out of the box solution.  It seems really odd to me that you would assert that there isn't.

Comment: If you want to use runtime proxies, do it.  I was suggesting an alternative that I think is a good idea.  If the runtime proxies makes you happy then do that.  You have a lot of flexibility there since Spring is under all of this.  Spring offers a lot of options for this sort of thing.

Comment: If you want to use a runtime proxy, what is it that you are not able to accomplish either with before or around advice?  In your description I don't see anything expressed that cannot be solved with one of those, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: With around advice then any exception thrown through the aop wrapper that is not explicitly declared on the method gets wrapped in an UndeclaredThrowableException.  This goes not only for methods asked to be proxied but for all methods on the bean that gets aop proxying.  Some code on the calling side of the proxy may be dependent on the exception types coming through the proxy so it's really not a good solution for us to have to explicitly add exception declarations to every method on every service where we are using the aop proxy.

Comment: And perhaps some would consider AST to be an out of the box solution but I wouldn't put myself in that category.  I've tinkered with AST in the past and the learning curve is pretty steep.  I don't want to have to know about 9 different compilation steps, which step to insert my transformation in, and learn an entire framework of code for walking class nodes, method nodes, etc.  It's just not trivial and I feel like the problem I'm trying to solve really should be.

Comment: I am sorry that I was not able to help you.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I appreciate the effort.